# We are trying to to run our C Program through node red on the raspberry pi 3 however we when deploy our flow nothing shows up in the debug window.

Tags: node.js, node-red

We are trying to to run our C Program through node red. In order to do that we used the exec node and tried to run the command sudo ./libpcap. We want to grab the output of this program and store it in Node Red for future use.
Listed below is our current flow we have looked up tutorials but none of them have gone over how to run a C program in terminal through node red. Every time we run the program nothing shows up in the debug screen.

[{"id":"f9524ab0.b871d8","type":"inject","z":"79884e02.cf776","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":100,"y":80,"wires":[["ea24d1e7.ae6d3"]]},{"id":"ea24d1e7.ae6d3","type":"exec","z":"79884e02.cf776","command":"sudo ./libpcap","addpay":false,"append":"","useSpawn":"false","timer":"","oldrc":false,"name":"","x":280,"y":120,"wires":[[],["9fc416e3.776448"],[]],"inputLabels":["node /home/pi/.node-red/libpcap"]},{"id":"9fc416e3.776448","type":"debug","z":"79884e02.cf776","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"payload","x":510,"y":120,"wires":[]}]

Comment: Where is the `libpcap` file? You should supply the full path to the file not just `./libcap`

Comment: It is in the /home/pi

Comment: Also you've only attached the debug node to the `stderr` output from the exec node. Connect the top output as well to get the `stdout` output

Comment: Thanks that helped we got a an output that says msg.payload:number but thats not what our program outputs should we add a function node to extract the right data from our program.

Comment: That sounds like you've attached to the bottom output (error code) not the top. Look the number up in the sudo man page

Answer (score 0):

There’s node-red-contrib-daemon for long running processes and options for handling the output/stdout that may be easier to work with in this case.